# Google API Places Detail : Not returning area name for Japan

Tags: json, google-maps, google-places-api

I want to use the google api places detail, in order to autocomplete and validate shipping address form for my e-commerce website in japan. The Area is properly return by "autocomplete", but I should use the "detail" in order to have the right information in the right field. Is there any way to get that information ?

In a first time I used "autocomplete" api in order to get an address prediction, this prediction give me an place_id.
Using this place_id in "detail" api I have all the information with field description, I used the json to fill the fields.

When using autocomplete I have the following JSON (sample), properly return me the area "Kawauchi" :

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=MYKEY&input=039-5201%20japan

```
"predictions" : [
      {
         "description" : "Kawauchi, Mutsu, Préfecture d'Aomori 039-5201, Japan",
         "id" : "b6097aa24e28b42610e3f1dcccbe6f5af8352b2a",
         "matched_substrings" : [
            {
               "length" : 8,
               "offset" : 37
            },
            {
               "length" : 5,
               "offset" : 47
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJNWWAxPUTnF8Ra2n2XG6s7mA",
         "reference" : "ChIJNWWAxPUTnF8Ra2n2XG6s7mA",
```

When using the place_id in order to get those address information the area is not returned :
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=MYKEY&placeid=ChIJNWWAxPUTnF8Ra2n2XG6s7mA&fields=address_components

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : {
      "address_components" : [
         {
            "long_name" : "039-5201",
            "short_name" : "039-5201",
            "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Mutsu",
            "short_name" : "Mutsu",
            "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Préfecture d'Aomori",
            "short_name" : "Préfecture d'Aomori",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Japon",
            "short_name" : "JP",
            "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
         }
      ]
   },
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I'm just expecting that "detail" return all the information. Is there any parameter to add to get that ?

Many thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this a known issue that has been reported in Google's Issue Tracker regarding missing sub-localities:

https://issuetracker.google.com/129089150

I recommend you star the issue to get updates on it and increase visibility.

Hope this helps.

Comment: sure! happy to assist :)